# Base class methods calling derived class methods, any possible solution?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am unable to find a solution to my problem other than modifying all the derived classes.

I have a `Base` class and some 1000 `Derived` classes inheriting from `Base`. Now, there is another class say `Container` which contains a vector of `Base` class pointers `std::vector<Base *> derivList`.

The above list is populated with the addresses of all the derived classes objects after creation.

All the files are in different translation units.

**What I want to do**:

`1)` To be able to call a single function of `Base` class  from `Container` class using the elements of vector in the Container which are pointing to different derived classes.

`2)` But when I call this function, inside that function I should go be able to access the `public members` of different `Derived` class to which the `Base` class pointer is pointing to.

```
class Base
{
  public: 
    virtual void someMethod();
    void containerCallsThisMethod();
};
void Base::containerCallsThisMethod()
{
  // I need to access the public functions of derived classes here
  // say: Derived1::calc(), Derived2::calc,.( I don't have derived class names here in  Base)
}

class Derived1:public Base
{
   public:
      void calc();
};

class Container
{
    std::vector<Base *> derivList;
    void execute();
};

void Container::execute()
{
    for(i = 0; i < derivList.size();i++)
    {
      derivList[i]->containerCallsThisMethod();
    }
}
```

**My constraints are**:

- I should not **Touch** the `Derived` class as it is very laborious, but still I can change the `Base` class.
- `Base` can't have a list( not even forward declarations) of `Derived` classes.

I thought I could do it through the `this` pointer as it has the `ClassName` type for `non-const` functions and it points to the derived class objects. But I am unable to call the `Derived` class methods using `this`.

Is there any way to do this without much labor, any specific design pattern or a hack?

Comment: Read about the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do in `Base::containerCallsThisMethod`? How to you want to distinguish between the different possible derived classes?

Comment: I have huge number of derived classes, I can't do this for every derived class.

Comment: @Bjorn Pollex: That is my problem, neither do I have a list nor the hearder files which contain the derived class declarations. Is there any way to do it using `this` because that should point to derived class.

Comment: Why can't you call the virtual function you need in the base function?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a base class with derived classes, the these derived classes override the function, lets call it `func()`, then that override of `func()` will be called. as far as i could find, the only solution to what you want is relaying on the good behavior of the derived classes or put `func()` as a static function, put it into friend class, or put it into a static inner class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can just declare `calc` as a (possibly `protected`) virtual function in `Base`. This only works if `calc` has exactly the same signature in all derived classes. In that case, no code must be changed in the derived classes. Now, when you call `this->calc` in `Base` it will be dispatched to the implementation in `Derived`.

```
class Base
{
  public: 
    vitrual void someMethod();
    void containerCallsThisMethod();

    virtual ~Base(); // Important !!
  protected:
    virtual void calc() = 0;
};
void Base::containerCallsThisMethod()
{
  calc(); // will call derived class implementation
}
```

Remember to add a virtual destructor to `Base` when you do this.

This works because when a method is declared virtual, it will be virtual in all derived classes as well, even if not explicitly specified so.

Answer (score 0):

If the

> public members of different Derived class

you need to access are methods with the same signature, but implemented differently in each **Derived** class (which is what your example seems to indicate) you are just finding yourself in the most basic use case of **virtual** method binding.

And you would then be very lucky : you only need to add the virtual keyword before the method signature in **Base** class definition.

```
class Base
{
    void containerCallsThisMethod()
    {
         calcDerivedMethod();
    }

    virtual void calcDerivedMethod();
}

class DerivedA : public Base
{
    void calcDerivedMethod()
    {
       //Specific implementation for DerivedA class.
    }
}
```

What happens here is exactly what you described as a requirement :
   Container method **execute()** call in turn **containerCallsThisMethod()** on every object it points to. This call ends up always being **Base::containerCallsThisMethod()**. But inside this last method, the call to **calcDerivedMethod()** is dispatched to the dynamic type of the pointer (i.e. the Derived class). You get this dynamic dispatch just by adding the **virtual** keyword in front of the **calcDerivedMethod()** declaration in **Base**.